# Recognizing rectangles from varying lines in c#

Tags: c#

Given an image with an undefined amount of rectangles that are separated by predefined lines with undefined coordinates (the lines in the image only represent the coordinates where the predefined lines should be).
Every rectangle should become a separate System.Drawing.Bitmap and put into an array of Bitmaps.

- The rectangles will always be rectangle shaped and will all have the same dimensions (so if you can find one proper rectangle, you may assume that the rest of the rectangles are the same).
- You may assume that all the lines in all images are a predefined fixed width (e.g. 5 pixels)
- The grid will always be parallel & perpendicular to the sides of the image.
- All lines will go from top to bottom, or side to side, even if it doesn't look like it in the image.
- The amount of rectangles is undefined (not always 4x4 as in the images)

These images are meant to find the rectangles, which will then be cut from the original image. But if I can cut these images in the proper rectangles, I should be able to do the same for the original image.

[image: One of the darker images]
[image: One of the lighter images]
[image: An image with imperfection]

I can imagine that this question is rather hard to understand; I've had a hard time trying to explain. All questions are more than welcome.

Comment: they are squares not rectangles :P

Comment: In these images they are, but they won't always be like this

Comment: I would start by looking at individual lines (horizontal or vertical) and check for changes in "blackness". When there are sudden changes, then the line is across the body of rectangles. No or gradual changes? That might be a border!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your question really is, so I'm assuming you are searching for an algorithm to detect your rectangles.
From the images it looks like you can separate the border lines of the rectangles with some kind of binarization filter from the background texture in the image.

I would try a [Hough transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) on your images to detect the rectangles and look for similar sized rectangles in the Hough space to narrow down the results. The Hough Transform can be easily implemented and is not very complicated. But I guess a bit of googling will get you a sample code as well.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I've tried it out, but like many of my ideas this takes way too long (the images I have to analyze are very big).
Now looking into a horizontal and vertical histogram.

Comment: Depending on how accurate the rectangle detection has to be, maybe a rescaling of the images is possible to cut on compute time?

Comment: Believe it or not, but I just thought of that myself
And believe it or not, I should have thought of that much sooner.
Thank you again!